# Proximity to object scale - Geometry nodes

Tags: transforms, geometry-nodes

I want to scale different single objects based on their distances to a cube / null.
I can't figure it out why the "Geometry Proximity" node fails. I've tried to connect it to the scale value in many different ways but as soon as I connect the "Distance"  output to anywhere, it gives me the red line in front of the Scale property. Can anyone help me find the cause?

[image: Scale an object with proximity to an other.]

Comment: You're trying to connect a blue diamond to a blue circle. GeoNodes added these extra socket types as they were needed, and it means you need to be extra careful. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what node you need but it's likely that you'll be able to feed your current arrangement through it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you need, but try something like this. It uses the *location* of Cube.001 to control the scale of the base Cube (based on their proximity - father away = larger scale). I added a math node, just to make it more clear what's happening (otherwise the cubes looked "attached" together). Let me know if this is in the right direction:

[image: Move]

This second image is the same setup, but with the movement/scale effect restricted to one axis, like your example (in this case X):

[image: MoveAxis]

It works with multiple objects, and works just as well with an empty. Note that the scale input is expecting a 3 value container, so you cannot "fine tune" the distance using a ColorRamp (or any other non-color manipulation), but you can use RGBCurves as it outputs 3 values - just remember that the R, G, and B channels are responsible for scaling the X, Y, and Z axes, respectively, so you can manipulate the scaling individually by axis if you want, or if you just want to keep the same (relative) proportions, only modify the Combined (C) curve:

[image: MoveEmpty]